# Path traversal animation in Shape-Shifter

Tags: android, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

I am using ShapeShifter at [ShapeShifter](https://beta.shapeshifter.design/)

I want to create a vector animation where a small rectangle traverses the border of a rectangle. Sounds like an easy animation to create!

Shapeshifter provides the trimPathStart, trimPathEnd and trimPathOffset animations.

However, I don't see animations that provide traversing a path!

I have tried creating a rectangle as a path, and then creating individual rectangles all along the border of the first rectangle. Then, animating with alpha and stroke-width for each of the smaller rectangles. However, this is not really what I am looking for.

**I need an animation technique that will translate the rectangle along the border of a main rectangle.**

How can I achieve this type of animation using ShapeShifter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a weird idea I explored. And use in my own applications.

Create dynamic SVG sprites with Template Literal Strings.

https://sprite-meister.github.io

Web Component is usable. Just not documented and refactored for laymans use.

https://github.com/sprite-meister/sprite-meister.github.io Source code has the UNLicense, you are free to do whatever you want with it

```html
<script src="https://sprite-meister.github.io/element.js"></script>

<sprite-meister duration="3s" width="180px">
  ${v1=10,v2=90,v3=20,v4=20,v5='black',v6=60,v7='grey',v8='fill="green"'}
  <g stroke="${v5}" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round">
    <line x1="${v3}"    y1="${v1}" x2="${v4}"    y2="${v2}"></line>
    <line x1="${v3+25}" y1="${v1}" x2="${v4+25}" y2="${v2}"></line>
    <line x1="${v3+50}" y1="${v1}" x2="${v4+50}" y2="${v2}"></line>
  </g>
  <rect id="knob" x="10" y="${15+ease({distance:v6})}" width="20" height="10" 
        stroke-width="2" stroke="${v7}" rx="3" ry="3" ${v8}=""></rect>
  <use href="#knob" x="25" y="${-ease({distance:v6})}"></use>
  <use href="#knob" x="50" y="${framenr > 10 ? -v6 + ease({distance:v6}) : -10}"></use>
</sprite-meister>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny! But I am trying to use Shape-Shifter since I will import it into Android Studio. I do not think the Sprite-Meister library lets you import the SVG animations to Android Studio?

Comment: You could use the generated **sprites** at the bottom of the page and draw them sequentially yourself. But that is a lot of SVG code to download, then use.